# Connecting UM7 inertial measurement unit through serial on python

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to connect the UM7 IMU to computer through serial, so I can further track motions on blender. Unfortunately, my knowledge of python is rather shallow. I am using pyserial, connecting to COM9 with default baudrate, etc and I have problems understanding what I get in result and how to decode it. So it looks as:

import serial
ser=serial.Serial(8)
ser.read(10)

I get a feed that looks like
b'\x18\xc8\xe0\x08/\x88(\x88(\xdd'
My first thought was that the feed is a hexadecimal but then again there are a lot of elements like additionals signs '?-+/' etc and letters that dont seem to be a part of a hex.

Could you explain me how to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

The UM7 IMU uses a binary protocol to efficiently transfer the data over the serial line.

I have just recently forked a project on github that does just that:

https://github.com/buxit/um7

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read IMU data from serial.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM24", 9600, timeout=1)

data = ser.readline()
s = data.decode()
s2 = s.strip("\r\n\t")
s2 = s2.split()
```